# dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-2, 1], but got 2)

Tags: pytorch

Why does the following error popup? What should be in this range and why? What does -2 dimension mean?

```
RuntimeError: dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-2, 1], but got 2)
```

This code will produce the error

```
import torch 

torch.bmm(torch.randn(1000, 784) , torch.randn(784, 10))
```

Comment: I do not understand the error per say. But I see why there is an error message. The number of matrices in both batches need to be the same. There is broadcasting with bmm. If you try this `torch.bmm(torch.randn(1000, 784, 1), torch.rand(1000, 1, 784))` it works.

Answer (score 3):

[**torch.mm**](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=mm#torch.mm):

> Performs a matrix multiplication of the matrices mat1 and mat2.
>
> If mat1 is a (n×m) tensor, mat2 is a (m×p) tensor, out will be a (n×p)
>       tensor.

[**torch.bmm**](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=bmm#torch.bmm):

> Performs a batch matrix-matrix product of matrices stored in batch1
>   and batch2.
>
> batch1 and batch2 must be 3-D tensors each containing the same number
>   of matrices.
>
> If batch1 is a (b×n×m) tensor, batch2 is a (b×m×p) tensor, out will be
>   a (b×n×p) tensor.

The following code snippet works.

```
import torch

x = torch.mm(torch.randn(100, 78) , torch.randn(78, 10))
bsize = 16
x = torch.bmm(torch.randn(bsize, 100, 78) , torch.randn(bsize, 78, 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `torch.bmm` implements the batch matrix-matrix product. For normal matrix-matrix product you need two have two 2D matrices in order to create the product.

With `torch.bmm` you can create the product even batch-wize but of course then you need to include the batch dimension, thus you need to two input 3 dimensional matrices.

About the how the are dimensions used in `torch.bmm`:

> If **batch1** is a *(b×n×m)* tensor, 
>   **batch2** is a *(b×m×p)* tensor, output will be a *(b×n×p)* tensor.

https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.bmm